# Creating a date picker in a fragment

Tags: android, button, datepicker, fragment, datepickerdialog

I just started learning Kotlin and my current target is to create a simple date picker in a fragment, after pressing a button.

As guideline I used the example, show by the [android developer docs for pickers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers). As template I used the bottom navigation standard template.

My question:
According to the example, I created a class `DatePickerFragment`. In the return line a method is referenced which needs a context as input. In the example `activity` is written. I don't know what to implement here to make the code work.

The error massages (refering to class DatePickerFragment):

1. 'onCreateDialog' overrides nothing
2. Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentActivity? but Context was expected

In the following I paste a bit of code. The whole code can also be found here:
https://github.com/andregreschat/DatePickerinFragmentTest

**DatePickerFragment CLASS:**

```
package de.datepickerinfragmenttest

import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.app.Dialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.DatePicker
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import java.util.*

class DatePickerFragment : DialogFragment(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle): Dialog {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return DatePickerDialog(activity, this, year, month, day)
    }

    override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user


    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
package de.datepickerinfragmenttest

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        fun showDatePickerDialog(v: View) {
            val newFragment = DatePickerFragment()
            newFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, "datePicker")
        }

    }


}
```

Fragment:

```
package de.datepickerinfragmenttest.ui.home

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import de.datepickerinfragmenttest.DatePickerFragment
import de.datepickerinfragmenttest.R
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)
        homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            textView.text = it
        })
        return root
    }
}
```

**Fragment Layout with the Button**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SetDate"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text_home"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What happens when you execute your code? What is the error you get?

Comment: @cewaphi The error massages (refering to class DatePickerFragment):

1. 'onCreateDialog' overrides nothing
2. Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentActivity? but Context was expected

Comment: In your `HomeFragment` I don't see any "showDatePickerDialog" method. Can you show it?

Answer (score 0):

I am somewhat wondering that you are setting up your `navigation` component but then you are not using it to move to your `DialogFragment`.

There are 2 other methods (rather than this `activity` attribute) you might want to call for getting the desired `Context` when instantiating the dialog:

1. `requireContext()`
2. `requireActivity()` (if you need to make sure an activity `Context` is passed)